# Limits in vector calc

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^4\sin(xy)}{x^2 + y^2} $$

now the textbook I'm using is very bad with giving examples - about a 150 pg text that condenses everything. So the method I first tried was to check $x=my^4$, with $m$ as any constant, but that didn't make things easier. The only other methods I know of are what i learned in calc 1- could I use 2 instances of hopitals on this to get rid of the zero in the denominator?

Comment: You have no accepted answers. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to polar coordinates. Let $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$. Then $x^2+y^2=r^2$. We have
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^4\sin(xy)}{x^2 + y^2} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{r^4 \sin^4 \theta \sin(r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta)}{r^2}=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^2 \sin^4 \theta \sin(r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta)=0.$$

Comment: nice, thanks---

Answer (score 3):

Use
$$
\left|\frac{y^4\sin (xy)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leqslant\frac{y^4}{y^2}\leqslant y^2
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: ahh wow didn't even think of that - thanks